# Rails: Sqlite3 related error when running Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, cucumber, gemfile

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'


group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end


group :test, :development do
  gem 'mysql2'
  gem "cucumber-rails", "~> 1.3.0"
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.9.0"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 0.7.2"
  gem "factory_girl", "~> 3.0.0"
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "heroku"
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

And I am in Ruby 1.9.3-p125 and Rails 3.2.2.

When I do `$ cucumber`, I get the following error:

```
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

Why would I be getting this error? I don't want to use the sqlite3 gem, and I don't know why when launching cucumber I am getting it.  I can launch the server without any problems...

Comment: Please provide your `config/database.yml` file

Comment: uDay, your comment made me solve this problem. I was declaring sqlite3 in database.yml. You might want to answer it, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because in your `config/database.yml` file the **test:** environment is given as `adapter: sqlite3` change it to `adapter: mysql2`. Tell me if this is not the issue.